# How to return a JsonResult to Razor Page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I'm new to ASP.net and Razor Pages. In the codes below, I'm trying to fill the District dropdownlist with values based on the State dropdownlist. Here's what I've got so far:

View:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascirpt" type="text/javascript">
    function GetDist(_stateId) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#select-state").html(procemessage).show();
        var url = "/Info/GetDistById/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { stateid: _stateId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Quận/Huyện</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $("#select-state").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" id="select-state" onchange = "javascript:GetDist(this.value);">
                @foreach (var state in Model.tbState)
                {
                    <option value=@state.StateId>@state.Statename</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 ">Quận/Huyện: </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" id="select-dist">
                @foreach (var dist in Model.tbDistrict)
                {
                    <option value=@dist.DistrictId>@dist.Districtname</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
```

On my cshtml.cs file I have this code. I did use `System.Web.Helpers` at the beginning of the code:

```cs
public IActionResult GetDistById(int stateid)
        {
            List<TbDistrict> list = new List<TbDistrict>();
            foreach (var q in tbDistrict)
            {
                if (q.StateId == stateid)
                    list.Add(q);
            }
            SelectList selectlist = new SelectList(list, "", "", 0);
            JsonResult result = Json(selectlist);
            return result;
        }
```

I found out that the Json() method only works with the `Controller` class in MVC, not a Razor `PageModel` class, so it gives error CS0103 "The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context". Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Returning non-views in a Razor Page context is somewhat odd (since the whole point about Razor Pages is to make it very view-focused). You can new up a `JsonResult` though using `return new JsonResult(…)`.

Comment: If you need to return JSON, then you should use a traditional controller and action, not a Razor Page. Razor Pages are designed to return views.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple issues.

1. For return json, you need to try the suggestion from @poke by using `return new JsonResult` like

   ```
   public IActionResult OnGetDistById(int stateid)
   {
       return new JsonResult(new Product { Id = stateid, Name = "Tom" });
   }
   ```
2. For action method in `PageModel`, its name should follow the suggestion from @Prakash by using `OnGetDistById`
3. For client side, its request url should be `https://localhost:44358/index?handler=distbyid&stateid=2` with specicying the `handler` and querystring `stateid`

Anyway, if you prefer request url like `/Info/GetDistById/`, you need to implement web api in your razor project instead of `PageModel`.

You could follow:

1. Add `ValuesController` in your project like

   ```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   public class ValuesController : Controller
   {
           // GET: api/<controller>
           [HttpGet]
           public IEnumerable<string> Get()
           {
           return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
           }        
   }
   ```
2. Configure route in `Startup.cs`

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
           routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

ASP Pages has usual `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods. If you need any additional calls to the same page via Ajax, then you will have to follow the `OnGet*` and `OnPost*` convention.

In the example you have given, you need to name the method as `OnPostDistById` and in the Javascript you need have the URL as `"/Info/DistById"`. Had that been a HTTP Get call, the method name would have been `OnGetDistById` and the URL would remain the same.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page) for more info.